# Filtering HTML tag with PHP function

Tags: php

I've created a function in PHP which gives me data between two HTML tags. For example:

```
<a><b><c>test</c></b></a>
```

If you give in input this string and the start ($tag_inizio) -final tag ($tag_fine) `<a>-</a>`, my function will return `<b><c>test</c></b>`.
Thats my code:

```
function get_tab($data, $tag_inizio, $tag_fine) {
    $len = strlen($data);
    $content = array();
    $i = 0;

    while (strpos($data, $tag_inizio, $i)) {

        if ($i > $len) {
            return $content;
        }

        $start = strpos($data, $tag_inizio, $i);
        $stop = strpos($data, $tag_fine, $start);
        $howmuch = $stop - $start;

        $content[] = trim(substr($data, $start + strlen($tag_inizio), $howmuch - strlen($tag_inizio)));

        $i = $stop;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

This function is working perfectly and never gave me output errors. I know is not perfect but still working. The problem is that if I give in input this string:

```
<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><b><a href="link">NAME</b></a>

            </td>

          <!-- <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><b>NAME</b></td> -->

            <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">

            </td>

          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">    9&nbsp;</td>

            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><img src="img\Flags\BRA.png" alt="Brasile" border="0"></td>

          <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">TEXT</td>

          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><b> 0.56.31</b></td>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">  20</td> 
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">0.17.16</td>

          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">   1</td>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"> 0.29.53</td>

          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">  11</td>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"> 0.09.22</td>


                <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">  1</td>


            <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1">S4</td>

                <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><b>
                 ------ 
                </b></td>
```

It works only if I use:

```
get_tab($var, "<td align=\"right\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font size=\"1\">", "</td>")
```

And

```
get_tab($var, "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font size=\"1\">", "</td>")
```

But no with:

```
get_tab($var, "<td align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><font size=\"1\">", "</td>")
```

Where is the problem? I know there is this text and I verified it with `preg_match()` function, but output array is empty.

Comment: If I remove "<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font size="1"><b><a href="link">NAME</b></a></td>" the script is working fine. The problem is that I'm doing scrapping and I can't edit what $var contains. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change to `while (strpos($data, $tag_inizio, $i) !== false)`

The first match is on the first line, when matching 'left', resulting in 0 which evaluates to false.

Comment: It works. Can you explain me the problem? I didn't catch it

Comment: strpos($data, $tag_inizio, $i) will return 0 as the match was in the first line of your text. This stops your while loop from continuing as it sees a 0 as false. Adding the !== false means it doesn't see the 0 as false. There are more detailed examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. Hope this helps.